# Is there any way to convert angular Js to Angular 2+ Or I should write new Code in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I've below code written in Angular.js. How can I convert it in Angular 2+. I tried using @angular/router in component.ts. But getting lot of errors.

I am new to angular so facing lot of issue while developing application.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/boomerang.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/plugins/rt.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/plugins/navtiming.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/plugins/auto-xhr.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/plugins/spa.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boomerangjs@1.650.0/plugins/angular.js"></script>



<script>
 BOOMR.init({ 
  ResourceTiming: {
    enabled: true,
    clearOnBeacon: true,    
  },
  Angular:{
    enabled:true
  },
  autorun: false,   
  instrument_xhr: false  

});


module.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
var hadRouteChange = false;
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
    hadRouteChange = true;
});

function hookAngularBoomerang() {
    if (window.BOOMR && BOOMR.version) {
        if (BOOMR.plugins && BOOMR.plugins.Angular) {
            BOOMR.plugins.Angular.hook($rootScope, hadRouteChange);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

if (!hookAngularBoomerang()) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("onBoomerangLoaded", hookAngularBoomerang);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e && e.propertyName === "onBoomerangLoaded") {
                hookAngularBoomerang();
            }
        });
    }
}
}])




BOOMR.subscribe('before_beacon', function(beaconData) {
  if (beaconData.u.indexOf("/")) {
    // take some action based on the page
    alert(beaconData["rt.start"]);
    alert(beaconData["rt.bmr"]);
  } 

});


</script>
```

I've to use it to measure angular 2+ performance.

Comment: This looks like an HTML document (contains `<script>` elements). Angular (2+) applications are typically transpiled using Node tools. It's not common to include dependencies with `<script>` tags. Usually they are defined in a package.json file.

Answer (score 2):

you have to start working from scratch as a new project on angular version 2.there is no way to convert angular js to angular 2